# How to show all data from multiple table using sql JOIN query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have following Mysql table :

1) products
2) product_images
3) product_date_time
4) product_menu
5) chef_profile

I need to show all data from those 5 table to a page called menu-details.php

All table have `foreign key` as `p_id` of `products` table id and Some table have multiple data of same `p_id`.

**To get this done I am using following mysql join query :**

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT p.p_id, p.p_title, p.p_description,

p.p_price, p.p_availability, p.delivery_option, p.event_location,

pimg.p_large_image, pimg.p_small_image, pdt.date, pm.p_menu_title, 

pm.p_menu_description, pm.p_menu_price, pm.p_menu_availability, chef.fname, 

chef.lname, chef.chef_details FROM products as p LEFT JOIN product_images as 

pimg ON p.p_id = pimg.p_id LEFT JOIN product_date_time as pdt ON pdt.p_id = 

p.p_id LEFT JOIN product_menu as pm ON pm.p_id = p.p_id LEFT JOIN 

chef_profile AS chef ON chef.u_id = p.u_id WHERE p.p_id =  '$mid' ") or 

die('wrong query');
```

**To show data I am using following php code :**

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);        
$menu_title =  htmlspecialchars($result['p_title']);
```

**My Questions**

1. Should I use 5 unique **sql query** to show data to that menu_details.php page ?
2. Now this query is showing single record from those table which have multiple data of same `p_id`. I need to show all data which have same `p_id` with multiple data. How can I do this ?
3. For example : I have following data in `product_images` table :

   ```
   pimg_id   p_large_image  p_id   u_id  

   1         name           203    25  
   1         name           204    26  
   1         name           204    25  
   1         name           205    27  
   1         name           205    28
   ```

So If I use php `while` loop it's showing all data from that table but it's should be show all data based on `p_id` for e.g `p_id` = 204

```
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo $menu_l_image = htmlspecialchars($result['p_large_image']);
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what you expect the result to look like?

Comment: Yes I have. let me show you

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: I should have specified the result of the query. What do you expect the rows of the result of the query to look like?

Comment: I want to use one query to show all data from multiple table based on same p_id

Comment: do you mean I need to use 5 sql query ?

Comment: So when trying to do this, you'll have varying amounts of data from each table for each product I'm guessing. You will get duplicates for each field depending on how many there are in each table for each product.

Comment: So what should I do now ?

Answer (score 0):

If the p.id is an integer remove the single quote form $mid

```
"SELECT 
    p.p_id, 
    p.p_title, 
    p.p_description,
    p.p_price, 
    p.p_availability, 
    p.delivery_option, 
    p.event_location,
    pimg.p_large_image, 
    pimg.p_small_image, 
    pdt.date, 
    pm.p_menu_title, 
    pm.p_menu_description, 
    pm.p_menu_price, 
    pm.p_menu_availability, 
    chef.fname, 
    chef.lname, 
    chef.chef_details 
    FROM products as p 
    LEFT JOIN product_images as pimg ON p.p_id = pimg.p_id 
    LEFT JOIN product_date_time as pdt ON pdt.p_id = p.p_id 
    LEFT JOIN product_menu as pm ON pm.p_id = p.p_id 
    LEFT JOIN chef_profile AS chef ON chef.u_id = p.u_id 
    WHERE p.p_id =  $mid "
```

of previus a proper sanitize of the $mid vars you can use

```
"SELECT 
    p.p_id, 
    p.p_title, 
    p.p_description,
    p.p_price, 
    p.p_availability, 
    p.delivery_option, 
    p.event_location,
    pimg.p_large_image, 
    pimg.p_small_image, 
    pdt.date, 
    pm.p_menu_title, 
    pm.p_menu_description, 
    pm.p_menu_price, 
    pm.p_menu_availability, 
    chef.fname, 
    chef.lname, 
    chef.chef_details 
    FROM products as p 
    LEFT JOIN product_images as pimg ON p.p_id = pimg.p_id 
    LEFT JOIN product_date_time as pdt ON pdt.p_id = p.p_id 
    LEFT JOIN product_menu as pm ON pm.p_id = p.p_id 
    LEFT JOIN chef_profile AS chef ON chef.u_id = p.u_id 
    WHERE p.p_id = ". $mid . ";"
```

Comment: let me use your query

Comment: Same result using this query !